# Why was Ray serving community service?

Tags: character, scorpion

In [</ Scorpion>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorpion_(TV_series)) season 2, Walter pleads guilty and is sentenced to community service. He then meets [Ray Spiewack](https://scorpion.fandom.com/wiki/Ray_Spiewack), who becomes his friend. It's never said why Ray was sentenced. I haven't found anything related.

As he's homeless and lives in his car, it might be possible that he may have done some petty stealing, or be fined and couldn't pay. I've always thought he had done minor offenses, but found no evidence.

**Do we know why Ray was serving community service?**